# code for getting linkedin accessToken using android

Tags: android-webview

this is the code which i used to get the accessToken

final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

```
final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
LinkedInApiClient client;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.notepad_list);





   mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

   mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

   mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);


   mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



   try

   {


       System.out.println("Fetching request token from LinkedIn...");



       liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);



    String    authUrl = liToken.getAuthorizationUrl();  
    System.out.println("authUrl=================================="+authUrl);





       mWebView.loadUrl(authUrl);




     mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyInterface()
     , "htmlcontent");
```

when 'mWebView.loadUrl(authUrl);' is executed the a user can allow the application for accessing . and redirect on the url with oauthToken and access_verifier which i able to see on the webview with this message:you have not permission to open this url with OauthTOken and access_verifier.

Now the question is how to get the access_verifier using my code so that make a call to get the accessToken.

***this is intent-filter ***

Answer (score 0):

You are using webview in layout. You cannot get accessToken from this way. You have to call browser which retrieve CALLBACK_URL. Use following code which will solve your problem.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory
                    .getInstance()
                    .createLinkedInOAuthService(
                            getResources().getString(R.string.consumer_key),
                            getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.consumer_secret));

            factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.consumer_key), getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.consumer_secret));

            liToken = oAuthService
                    .getOAuthRequestToken(WelcomeActivity.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL); 

            i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                .parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));
            startActivity(i);
        } 

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
    accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);  
}
```

Put this code into your activity tag in .manifest

```
<intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="callback"
                android:scheme="linkedin" />
        </intent-filter>
```